# How to get latitude and longitude from a full address (country, city, etc.)?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get coordinates from the total address of the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923398/how-to-get-coordinates-from-the-total-address-of-the-content)

How can I implement code for getting latitude and longitude from a full address (country, city, etc.) provided by the user and show them on `MapView`?