# how to get coordinates from the total address of the content?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am getting total address and coordinates of the location address but I need only coordinates to show on the google map. How is it possible in iPhone?

```
- (void)geocode {
    [SVGeocoder geocode:addressField.text
             completion:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                 UIAlertView *alertView;

                 if(!error && placemarks) {
                     SVPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                     NSLog(@"%@",placemarks);
                     alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Placemark Found!" message:[placemark description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 } else {
                     alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 }

                 [alertView show];
                 [alertView release];
             }];
```

the response of the geocoded

> "{\n    address =     {\n        City = Nalgonda;\n        Country =
>   India;\n        CountryCode = IN;\n        State = \"Andhra
>   Pradesh\";\n    };\n    coordinate =     {\n        latitude =
>   \"17.05239\";\n        longitude = \"79.26718\";\n    };\n
>   formattedAddress = \"Nalgonda, Andhra Pradesh, India\";\n}"

Comment: I think you should take a look at this guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Just read the documentation (reverse geocoding) or try the search feature on stackoverflow, preeeetty sure I have seen this question already.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You really should improve your existing question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920640/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-full-address-country-city-etc) instead of opening a new one.

Comment: I merged your previous question into this one, as it is a much better question. However, in the future, please just edit your original.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
   double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
   NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
   NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
   if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\":" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\":" intoString:nil]) {
          [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
          if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\":" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\":" intoString:nil]) {
              [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
          }
        }
    }
   CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
   center.latitude = latitude;
   center.longitude = longitude;
   return center;
}
```

Comment: Why using the google maps api (directly), when you have all the classes ready in Obj-C?